# why Job service doesn't start within the specified time?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I scheduled a job and I made it repeatable by setPeriodic() function every 2 hours, the problem is my service doesn't start within the specified time, and sometimes doesn't start at all, I know that starting from android O job services doesn't start when device is idle or at doze mode. Is there any way to make sure that my jobservice will start even if not at the specified time.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the broadcast in your app. And then start service from broadcast receiver, but if you don't show any UI/or foreground notification you have a little time to keep your background service running. Think about foreground service